# Android: Can't find my package folder to put the database file in it?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am new in using File Explorer in eclipse as well as Android.

I have created a database using `SQLite` and added few data. The database is named *dbtaxi*.

My package name is `com.syariati.finalProject`

Then I saved this device database onto my desktop to help me check its content using `SQLite Manager`, `firefox addons`. Then I have added some data using SQLite Manager, which is possible is causing the problem.

My requirement is to replace database in my package (`com.syariati.finalProject/Databases/dbtaxi`) with `dbtaxi` on my Desktop. But, I can't find the path `com.syariati.finalProject`.

Need help! Thank you.

Comment: you can see your db under /data/data/com.syariati.finalProject/Databases/dbtaxi

Comment: thank you. I tried using "push" in explorer, and I think it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your db is in a private folder `"data/data/com.syariati.finalProject/databases/dbtaxi"`. You cannot access that folder without rooting the phone.

Another option is to copy the db to that folder programatically.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;

public class FileUtils{
    public static void copyFile(File in, File out) 
        throws IOException 
    {
        FileChannel inChannel = new
            FileInputStream(in).getChannel();
        FileChannel outChannel = new
            FileOutputStream(out).getChannel();
        try {
            inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(),
                    outChannel);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        finally {
            if (inChannel != null) inChannel.close();
            if (outChannel != null) outChannel.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        FileUtils.copyFile(new File(args[0]),new File(args[1]));
  }
}
```

Comment: I read this article http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/
and I found it's very complicated. Since I still don't understand android structure.

Comment: That article says put your database file under `your_project_folder/assets/dbtaxi` It will be automatically copied to phone with eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

It's in "/data/data/com.syariati.finalProject/databases".

Answer (score 0):

```
/data/data/com.syariati.finalProject/databases
```

.
.
.
.